# MySQLBackup in c#

Tags: c#, mysql

How to solve this error ?

```
Error   1   Assembly 'MySqlBackup, Version=2.0.9.2, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'MySql.Data, Version=6.9.9.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' which has a higher version than referenced 
assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=6.3.6.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d'    c:\Users\Mohammed Abdullah\Desktop\MySqlBackup.dll  mobile_shop
```

Comment: Um, update to version 6.9.9.0 of MySql.Data?

Answer (score 0):

Add reference to

> MySql.Data

in you cs project